Android native Back button not working properly
I have an Android app developed in Flutter. My native Android (phone) BACK button is not working properly. no matter how many pages i visit, when i press BACK it doesnt return me to the previous visited page, instead is exit from my app. i dont know where the native behaviour has changed. i tried WillPopScope (even if it is deprecated), PopScope (but without the confirmation dialog). i also tried tu build a list with visited pages so that pressing the back button will return me to previous visited page from that list. Nothing Worked. Phone BACK button is throwing me out of my app
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'menu_page.dart';
import 'user_page.dart';
import 'statistici_page.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phoneId;
  final String idHash;

  const MainScreen({super.key, required this.phoneId, required this.idHash});

  @override
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 2; // Index pentru pagina de statistici
  late Widget _currentPage; // Pagina curentă afișată
  final List<Widget> _pageStack = []; // Stack pentru istoria paginilor
  final List<String> _visitedPages = []; // Array pentru paginile vizitate

  // Variabilă pentru a controla navigarea
  bool canPopBoolVar = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentPage = const StatisticiPage(); // Setați pagina implicită la statistici
    _pageStack.add(_currentPage); // Adăugați pagina inițială în stack
    _visitedPages.add('StatisticiPage'); // Adăugați în array-ul de pagini vizitate
  }

  void _onBottomNavTap(int index) {
    if (index == 2) {
      _logout(); // Apelare logout
      return; // Oprește funcția după logout
    }

    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;

      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          _currentPage = MenuPage(onNavigate: _onNavigate); // Navigare la MenuPage
          _visitedPages.add('MenuPage'); // Adaugă la paginile vizitate
          break;
        case 1:
          _currentPage = UserPage(onNavigate: _onNavigate); // Navigare la UserPage
          _visitedPages.add('UserPage'); // Adaugă la paginile vizitate
          break;
        case 2:
          _currentPage = const StatisticiPage(); // Pagina implicită
          _visitedPages.add('StatisticiPage'); // Adaugă la paginile vizitate
          break;
        default:
          _currentPage = const StatisticiPage(); // Pagina fallback
          _visitedPages.add('StatisticiPage'); // Adaugă la paginile vizitate
      }

      _pageStack.add(_currentPage); // Adaugă pagina curentă în stack
    });
  }

  // Navigare la alte pagini din aplicație
  void _onNavigate(Widget page, String title) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = page; // Setează pagina curentă
      _pageStack.add(page); // Adaugă pagina în stack
      _visitedPages.add(title); // Adaugă titlul în array-ul de pagini vizitate
    });
  }

  // Logout funcționalitate
  Future<void> _logout() async {
    bool confirmLogout = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Confirmare Ieșire'),
          content: const Text('Sigur doriți să vă delogați?'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: const Text('Anulează'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: const Text('Delogare'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    if (confirmLogout == true) {
      const FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
      final allKeys = await storage.readAll();
      final preserveSet = {'key1', 'key2'}; // Cheile pe care vrei să le păstrezi
      final keysToDelete = allKeys.keys.where((key) => !preserveSet.contains(key)).toList();

      for (var key in keysToDelete) {
        await storage.delete(key: key);
      }

      if (!mounted) return;

      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginScreen(phoneId: widget.phoneId),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return false; // Previne închiderea aplicației
        }
        return true; // Permite închiderea aplicației
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App Title'), // Titlu aplicație
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: _currentPage, // Afișează pagina curentă
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onBottomNavTap,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              label: 'Meniu',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'User',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
              label: 'Logout',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i want the native functionality of phone BACK button

The issue occurs because you're not using Flutter's Navigator for navigation. Instead, you're manually updating _currentPage and managing a custom _pageStack. As a result, when the back button is pressed, Flutter doesn't have any routes to pop, so it exits the app.
Try something like this for showing a new page instead:
void _onNavigate(Widget page) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page),
  );
}


Ok, i tried Navigator.push, it is OK (regarding BACK button functionality) even if menus background color changed to black (fixed). But the BottomNavigationBar disappeared from every visited page. and i want that BottomBar to be present on evey page of my app (even when is visit MenuPage and UserPage)

Ah, now I get you. You could try to use the thing before, but in onWillPop you should rather change the selected index of the page to the one before instead of Navigator.of(context).pop();. You would probably need to hold a history of that and return false so the app doesn't close.
